# Triggering another model's data to change (M2M) based on this model

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, relationship

Basically, I am trying to use data from one model to trigger a switch in another model.

If my invoice object is linked with a file, I want the file to be "locked" (a boolean).

I find that when I save the invoice, after linking it with a file, it doesn't register that invoice_file.count() is > 0 - until the next time I open up the invoice and save it AGAIN.  Note that I am doing the evaluation after calling super() though, so I find this to be confusing at best.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
...
invoice_file = models.ManyToManyField(UploadFile, null = True, blank = True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Invoice: saving!')
        super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'invoice_file count: %i' % self.invoice_file.count()
        if self.invoice_file.count() > 0:
            for invoice_file in self.invoice_file.all():
                if(invoice_file.locked_status(1)) != 1: raise Exception('Couldn\'t set file locked status to 1 on file %s' % invoice_file.filename)
```

This triggers a function in the UploadFile model:

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
...
def locked_status(self, stat):
    print('Locked status called.')
    if stat == 1:
        self.locked = True
        self.save()
        return 1
    elif stat == 0:
        self.locked = False
        self.save()
        return 0

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print 'UploadFile: Saving!'
    super(UploadFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Not sure how to fix your problem specifically, but try using Django 1.2's m2m changed signal: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed

Comment: Thanks Spike!  Funny you should mention signals, I just removed them as they were cluttering up my code and I find it easier just to override save() and delete().  However it seems like signals offer a finer degree of control, I may just re-instate them and see if I can get a different result.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following line:

```
if self.invoice_file.count() > 0:
```

If you're going to do a database hit, you may as well do it by retrieving all of the files associated with an invoice. This should have the added benefit of retrieving a 'fresh' view of related objects.

The problem is probably deeper though. ManyToMany fields can not be saved until its containing model has been saved. An example:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    commenters = models.ManyToManyField(User)

me = User.objects.get(username='Josh')
p = Post(title="ManyToManyExample")
p.commenters.add(me) # error, Post does not yet have an ID.
p.save()
p.commenters.add(me) # success!
```

Your `invoice_file` field is inaccurately named. It should be called `invoice_files`, since it is a collection. In your `Invoice.save` method you're attempting to iterate over a related collection before you've added any `UploadFile`s to that collection. I'd suggest adding a method to your `Invoice` model.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    ...

    def add_invoice_file(self, uploaded_file):
        self.invoice_files.add(uploaded_file) # error if the Invoice hasn't been saved yet
        for invoice_file in self.invoice_files.all(): 
            status = invoice_file.locked_status(1)
            if status != 1:
                raise Exception('Blah')
```

If an Invoice is associated with a large number of files, instead of using `.all()`, you should do `self.invoice_files.filter(locked=False)`. It might even be worth doing that anyway to avoid a whole lot of database saves that are unnecessary.